# Actsaswizard Rails Plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I'm having a problem implementing the example in the actaswizard readme, and I was wondering if my error would be obvious to anyone here.

My controllers, models, and migrations are exactly as shown here: https://github.com/adkron/actsaswizard

My routes are as follows:

```
match 'test' => 'employees#new'
resources :employees
```

However when I navigate to localhost/test I recieve the following error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `state' for #<Employee:0x00000001c22ad0>):
  app/controllers/employees_controller.rb:10:in`edit'

Does anyone recognize this error, or have any advice on how to get around it? Thanks in advance for any help! In addition, if you know of any good guides or additional examples using this plugin I'd be grateful for them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the actsaswizard uses the AASM (acts as state machine) to navigate you through the steps. That is why you need to specify a field "state" for the model that actsaswizard! This means that you must run a migration that makes a column named state of string type. Let me know if that worked!

Comment: You are absolutely right. In fact, this was in the example code, but I missed it, woops : / But awesome job figuring it out and thanks for taking the time to answer!